# Url doesn't correct after login

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular9

after that I do login I need to redirect to home page but in the url I read `/home/login` also if the url must be only `/home`. After the login I do:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home']);
```

After in  the url I read that the app calls homeComponent and the page is loaded, but the url is wrong because I read `/home/login`(I use /login to authenticate).
this in my app.ruting:

```
 { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'login', loadChildren: () => import("").then(m =>
      m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], loadChildren: () => import("..").then(m =>
      m.HomeModule)
  },
```

My guard is:

```
 canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
        if (this.autenticazionService.isUserLogged()) {          
            return true;
        } else {
            this.autenticazionService.logout();
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your route gaurd is redirecting to the the login route which would be having the path as 'login'. Try to change it to '/login' in the route gaurd and check. For non authentic user it would redirect to /login

Answer (score 0):

try this in your `''` path:

```js
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
```